# Find item in initializer list without requiring a temporary object

Tags: c++

Finding a string in a set of strings, I can of course use std::find, std::upper_bound or std::lower_bound, but all of those I must pass begin and end iterators.

Now - I have a set of strings that I wanna match, and a variable. The set of strings is known in compile time, and I would pretty much like to remove the verboseness of the current calls to something as simple as

```
if (std::find({"first", "string", "here"}, searchedStr) != std::notfound)
```

now, I know that std::notfound doesn't exists, this is just to Illustrate.

Do I have something like this on C++? Looking on the docs I couldn't find a thing. I also can't use std::set because of the red-black tree implementation and that would (my assumption here) make things slower.

Comment: You have to look at any **range** library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `initializer_list`. Use a *variadic template* instead:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
bool matches_any(const T& needle, const Ts&... haystack)
{
    // You might want to be smarter here and use `strcmp` if
    // comparing C-style strings.
    return ((needle == haystack) || ...);
}
```

I'm using a C++17 *fold expression* above, but there are alternatives for C++11 and C++14 *(look for `for_each_argument`)*.

Usage:

```
if(matches_any(searchedStr, "first", "string", "here")) { /* ... */ }
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OzkkZFK7Hx48IIMs)

Comment: that is AWESOME. <3